# Android View Binding with some Views in Base Classes

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-viewbinding

I'm migrating an existing app from the old `findViewById()` to View Binding. My fragments use inheritance extensively and common views are stored in various fragments in the inheritance hierarchy. For example...

```
class OverPaidQuotaBillingIssueFragment<FragmentOverPaidQuotaBinding> extends FixBillingIssueFragment {
    Button upgradeButton;
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    FragmentOverPaidQuotaBinding createviewbinding() {
        return FragmentOverPaidQuotaBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    }
}

abstract class FixBillingIssueFragment<VB extends ViewBinding> extends BaseFragment {
    TextView explanationTextView;   
}

abstract class BaseFragment<VB extends ViewBinding> extends Fragment {
    VB binding;
    ProgressBar spinner;
    
    abstract @NonNull VB createviewbinding();
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.binding = createviewbinding();
        return this.binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

Since a ton of my fragments throughout the app need a progress bar, I've got that defined in my BaseFragment and it is auto-controlled for lots of common situations by the BaseFragment code.

Likewise, all of the FixBillingIssueFragment-based screens will at least have a TextView that will contain the explanation of what is wrong.

And then the top level class OverPaidQuotaBillingIssueFragment would have specific UI elements to handle that situation, like an upgrade button.

I've put together an arrangement so that I can define the binding in the BaseFragment and try to reduce boilerplate as much as I can, but my problem is in `FixBillingIssueFragment` and `BaseFragment`.

`FixBillingIssueFragment` and `BaseFragment` need to be able to interact with their `explanationTextView` and `spinner`, but neither of them know what the real type of their ViewBinding class is, so they don't know that it has those fields in it.

Due to the nature of my layouts and the type of views we're talking about, I can't just segregate the common layout items into separate files in order to inflate them separately.

I don't really want to have the top-level class (`OverPaidQuotaBillingIssueFragment`) have to capture the view references for it's parent classes, because then every top-level class would have to have duplicated code capturing that view reference to store it in the parent class.

But the only other option I can think of is to have the abstract parent classes capture the references it wants by calling `findViewById()` which really seems like I'm writing a lot of code to replace `findViewById()` only to have to resort to still using `findViewById()`.

Is there another option I'm missing? Any suggestions are appreciated.